# Django, Queryset exists, but accessing [0] results in index error

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
     creator_payouts = self.filter(paid=False)
     processed_user_ids = []

     if not creator_payouts.exists():   // here I check the existence
         return

     for creator_payout in creator_payouts:
         do_something()

     creator_payouts.update(paid=True)  // maybe this does something?

     CreatorRecord.objects.filter(
         user__in=processed_user_ids,
         created_for__lte=creator_payouts[0].created_for // error here
     ).update(processed_for_payout=True)
```

I'm getting index error at `creator_payouts[0]` at the end of the code above.

Why am I getting the error, especially I rule out the empty list case by `creator_payouts.exists()` condition above

Comment: why do you assume that creator_payouts = self.filter(paid=False) will return a list?

Answer (score 1):

Well when you update the `creator_payouts`, then the database is updated with `paid=True`. As `creator_payouts` it a lazy queryset and and when you call `creator_payouts[0]` to evaluate it, it gets empty queryset. So you need to store the intial values somewhere with forceful evaluation. Like this:

```
if not creator_payouts.exists():   // here I check the existence
         return

for creator_payout in creator_payouts:
    # or store the first creator_payout in a variable here
    do_something()

unpaid_creator_payouts_list = list(creator_payouts)  # force evaluation

creator_payouts.update(paid=True)


 CreatorRecord.objects.filter(
         user__in=processed_user_ids,
         created_for__lte=unpaid_creator_payouts_list[0].created_for // or use the first stored payout_creator in previous loop
     ).update(processed_for_payout=True)
```

Or run the update operation after `CreatorRecord` filter.

Answer (score 0):

`creator_payouts` is queryset. If want get first better try `creator_payouts.first()` instead of `creator_payouts[0]`.

```
 CreatorRecord.objects.filter(
     user__in=processed_user_ids,
     created_for__lte=creator_payouts.first().created_for
 ).update(processed_for_payout=True)
```